# Fetching Image from URL using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am trying to fetch important images and not thumbnail or other gifs from the Wikipedia page and using following code. However the "img" is coming as length of "0". any suggestion on how to rectify it.

Code :

```
import urllib
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

html = urllib2.urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page")

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

imgs = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"image"})
```

Also if someone can explain in detail that how to use the findAll by looking at "source element" in webpage. That will be awesome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `a` tags on the page have an `image` class, not `div`:

```
>>> img_links = soup.findAll("a", {"class":"image"})
>>> for img_link in img_links:
...     print img_link.img['src']
... 
//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1f/Stora_Kronan.jpeg/100px-Stora_Kronan.jpeg
//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4b/Christuss%C3%A4ule_8.jpg/77px-Christuss%C3%A4ule_8.jpg
...
```

Or, even better, use `a.image > img` [`CSS selector`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
>>> for img in soup.select('a.image > img'):
...      print img['src']
//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1f/Stora_Kronan.jpeg/100px-Stora_Kronan.jpeg
//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4b/Christuss%C3%A4ule_8.jpg/77px-Christuss%C3%A4ule_8.jpg 
...
```

UPD (downloading images using [`urllib.urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve)):

```
from urllib import urlretrieve
import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))
for img in soup.select('a.image > img'):
    img_url = urlparse.urljoin(url, img['src'])
    file_name = img['src'].split('/')[-1]
    urlretrieve(img_url, file_name)
```

Comment: @LonelySoul sure, check the `UPD` section.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any div tags with a class called 'image' on that page.

You could get all the image tags and throw away ones that are small.

```
imgs = soup.select('img')
```