# Relative path to Absolute paths of images scraped from websites in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, relative-path, absolute-path

Iv scraped a website for images which will then be downloaded, however to be able to download them i need to find the absolute path of the images as this is what iv managed to scrape:

`2001.JPG
big.jpg
pics.gif
gchq.jpg`

all of these images are stored in the variable `images` im looking for one function which could find all of the absolute paths at once and store them in a variable?

This is the code i use to scrape the images:

`images = re.findall(r'src=[\"|\']([^\"|\']+)[\"|\']',webpage.decode())`

(i've had a look at various other similar questions on here but none seem to do multiple images at once)

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great and any suggestions for the downloading of them as well.

Comment: You may find the relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357317/fetching-image-from-url-using-beautifulsoup

Comment: show us (a minimal example of) the code you used to scrape the image name. Easiest would be to fetch the total path in this step

Comment: @MaartenFabré edited it

Comment: Don't use regexes to process HTML! BeautifulSoup is both simpler and more robust in it. For the remaining part of your question, HTTP protocol says that relative paths are relative to the parent of current url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With BeautifulSoup & urllib you should be able to collect the images in a webpage, iterate and download them.

```
from urllib import urlretrieve
import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = "<your_url>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))
for img in soup.select('img'):
    img_url = urlparse.urljoin(url, img['src'])
    file_name = img['src'].split('/')[-1]
    urlretrieve(img_url, file_name)
```

Python 3 compatible code,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen, urlretrieve
from urllib.parse import urljoin

url = "<url>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url))

for img in soup.find_all('img'):
    img_url = urljoin(url, img['src'])
    file_name = img['src'].split('/')[-1]
    urlretrieve(img_url, file_name)
```

Comment: does this work in python 3.6? aren't some of the modules renamed?

Comment: @JDoe Absolutely right! I'll be adding python 3. compatible code here.